# How to join between two tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

```
PC
----------------------------------
| PCID   | PCName| IPAdd | CLnum |
----------------------------------
|   1    |  PC1  |192.X.1|   1   |
|   2    |  PC2  |192.x.2|   1   |
|   3    |  PC3  |192.x.3|   1   |
----------------------------------

Date
----------------------------------
| DateID |  Date | Time |  PCID  |
----------------------------------
|    1   |2/12/18| 17:05|    1   |
|    2   |2/12/18| 17:14|    1   |
|    3   |2/12/18| 17:18|    1   |
|    4   |2/12/18| 17:36|    1   |
|    5   |2/12/18| 18:23|    2   |
|    6   |2/12/18| 18:26|    2   |
|    7   |2/12/18| 18:28|    3   |
----------------------------------

SELECT t1.PCID, t1.PCName, t1.IPAdd, t1.CLnum, t2.date, t2.time 
FROM pc t1 JOIN date t2 ON t2.PCID = t1.PCID 
WHERE t2.PCID= t1.PCID and t2.date>=date order by time desc limit 1
```

I tried using the query above but the result I needed is like this:

```
example:
-------------------------------------------------
| PCID | PCName | IPAdd | CLnum |  Date  | Time |
-------------------------------------------------
|  1   |   PC1  |192.x.1|   1   |02/12/18| 17:36|
|  2   |   PC2  |192.x.2|   1   |02/12/18| 18:26|
|  3   |   PC3  |192.x.3|   1   |02/12/18| 18:28|
-------------------------------------------------
```

What I'm trying to do is get the time in which each PC is last used on a selected date. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by `and t2.date>=date ` in the `where` clause? Also, please mention what you're expecting in the resultset. I cannot make that out by your result-table.

Comment: sorry i actually took that code from my Php. what i'm trying to do is get the time in which each PC is last used on a selected date.

Comment: If your mysql columns are case-sensitive, this can't work.

Comment: (Aside: when asking questions, please don't apologise for your English. It seems OK to me, but we edit that out anyway, since it is not part of the problem. Thanks!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are looking for the max(time) for your values:

```
SELECT   t1.pcid, 
         t1.pcname, 
         t1.ipadd, 
         t1.clnum, 
         t2.date, 
         Max(t2.time ) 
FROM     pc t1 j oin date t2 
ON t2.pcid = t1.pcid 
WHERE    t2.pcid= t1.pcid 
AND      t2.date>=date 
GROUP BY t1.pcid, 
         t1.pcname, 
         t1.ipadd, 
         t1.clnum, 
         t2.date 
ORDER BY t1.pcid
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm actually looking for something like this.